# How to use mouse click in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I was working on an animation on processing. Then, I have a question about the lights. Normally, my code is more long. However, I made a simple code which can usefull also for the beginners.

```
boolean isOn = false;             // Variable keeping the state of the light
float sphereSize = 100;           // The size of Shpere
float xS = 200; yS = 200; zS = 0; // The coordinates of Sphere

void setup()
{
  size(400, 400, P3D);
  noStroke();
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  if (isOn)                       // Checks the state in which the light should be
    lights();
  translate(xS, yS, zS);          // Translate the sphere to the middle of window
  sphere(sphereSize);             // Making a sphere for see ligts
}

void mouseReleased() {            // This function is automatically called in draw method
  if (isOn)                       // After a click the state of the light is inverted
      isOn = false;
    else isOn = true;
}
```

So, I want to work light only if the mouse click on the sphere. If the mouse click outside the sphere, it will not work. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dist()`](https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html) to compute the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the mouse position ([`mouseX`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseX.html), [`mouseY`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseY.html)) and the center of the sphere (`xS`, `yS`).
If the distance is less or equal than the radius (`sphereSize`), then switch the light:

```java
void mouseReleased() {

    float distance = dist(xS, yS, mouseX, mouseY);
    if (distance <= sphereSize)
        isOn = !isOn;
}
```